# Port error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, coffeescript, google-chrome-devtools

I've been googling around extensively trying to remedy this problem but can't seem to find a solution. I'm trying to do the simple task of setting up a listener and sender in my Chrome extension.

**My manifest**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "my app",
  "description": "text",
  "version": "0.1",
  "background":{
    "scripts":["background.js"]
  },

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      // http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns.html
      "matches": ["http://myurl.com/*"],
      "js": ["jquery-1.9.1.min.js", "myapp.js"],
      "all_frames": true
    }
  ], 
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "/icons/icon-mini.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

**In my background JS**

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
    console.log(response.farewell);
  });
});
```

**In my popup.js (rendered by coffeescript, please forgive the sort of strange syntax)**

```
(function() {

  $(function() {});

  chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (console.log(sender.tab)) {
      "from a content script:" + sender.tab.url;
    } else {
      "from the extension";
    }
    if (request.greeting === "hello") {
      return sendResponse({
        farewell: "goodbye"
      });
    }
  });

}).call(this);
```

**In my myapp.js**

```
chrome.extension.sendMessage({
      greeting: "hello"
    }, function(response) {
      return console.log(response.farewell);
    });
```

I've followed [the tutorial](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html#simple). Not sure why this isn't working. I'm pretty decent with JS, very unclear as to why this is behaving strangely. Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: What is the result of your code? Any errors?

Comment: the error is in the title of this post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is more than one problem with this code so let me break it down.

From what I see you are trying to send a message from your content script to your popup and there is a background page not doing anything.

**Problem #1**

The code in the popup.js, besides being strangely convoluted, is not a background page. It only runs when the `popup` is open, so it will not be able to listen for the message.

**Problem #2**

The code in the background page is using the depreciated `getSelected` method to send a message to the content script. The content script has no listener.

The result of these two things is this:

```
Background page -> content script (no listener)
Content Script -> extension pages (no listener)
```

I suggest making your background page the hub of your communications. If you need to communicate between your popup and content script make it `popup -> content script` and use `sendResponse()` to reply.

Edit: Here is an example of the message passing you would want. Just replace with your variables.

**Content Script**

```
...
//get all of your info ready here

chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(message,sender,sendResponse){
  //this will fire when asked for info by the popup
  sendResponse(arrayWithAllTheInfoInIt);
});
```

**Popup**

```
...
chrome.tabs.query({'active': true,'currentWindow':true},function(tab){
  //Be aware 'tab' is an array of tabs even though it only has 1 tab in it
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab[0].id,"stuff", function(response){
    //response will be the arrayWithAllTheInfoInIt that we sent back
    //you can do whatever you want with it here
    //I will just output it in console
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks BeardFist. I have an array in my content script that I'd like to display in my popup. That's ultimately what I'm trying to do. Any suggestions towards doing that?

Comment: @ZackShapiro I suggest using `chrome.tabs.sendMessage` from your popup to initiate a connection with the content script. Put a `chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener` in your content script. Then use `sendResponse(stuff)` to send the array back to the popup. I can write up an example if you want.

Comment: Thanks @BeardFist! An example would be awesome!

Comment: @ZackShapiro I added a short example to my answer. I didn't include the background page but you could do a similar `popup -> background` message passing setup.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in a background page and my solution was to ensure that the tab had completed loading before trying to send it a message.

If the tab has not fully loaded, the content script will not have started and will not be waiting for messages yet.

Here's some code:

```
 chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
   if (changeInfo.status === 'complete') {
     // can send message to this tab now as it has finished loading
   }
 }
```

So if you want to send a message to the active tab, you can make sure it has completed loading first.